# bash + dose for loop have limitation?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

I wondering what the max number that  for-loop command can support

for example I have 900 .txt file

when I run the for loop , I see that all files was matched with grep

but dose for loop can read for example 20000 files ? what the limitation ?

```
ls | grep .txt | wc -l

950
```

the for-loop

```
 for FILE_NAME in ` ls | grep .txt `
 do
 grep WORD $FILE_NAME 
 done
```

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be using `ls` here anyway... `for FILE_NAME in *.txt`

Comment: WHY -1? what bad with my question?

Comment: what do you mean by `grep perl $FILE_NAME`

Comment: this is only example ( by grep some file )

Comment: i didnt get your intention. but `grep perl` is completly wrong. if you want to grep the output of perl use pipe

Comment: ignore the grep perl - this could be some other comnmand as grep WORD , this is example please focus on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A built-in construct like a `for` loop has no maximum:

```
for FILE_NAME in *.txt; do
```

can expand `*.txt` into as many names as exist in the current directory. Since `bash` expands the pattern *and* iterates over the result, it can manage the list itself. The same holds for a built-in command like

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt
```

since `bash` both expands the pattern and executes the `printf` in the interpreter process itself.

Contrast that with

```
ls *.txt
```

Here, we know have two separate programs (the `bash` interpreter and `ls`) communicating via the operating system's API for passing arguments to a command. `bash` must expand the pattern to all matching files, them fit them into the array used to pass arguments to a new process (think `argv` of the `main()` function). *This* array has a maximum size defined by your OS, and if there are too many matching files, will cause a "Command line too long" or "Too many arguments" error.

Comment: upvote for you -can you also upvote for me? ( I think my question with good quality ( not understand why I get -2 )

Answer (score 0):

A test run on 1959 file would be

```
$ ls | wc -l
1960
```

Using a for loop

```
$count=0
$ for file in *
> do 
>(( count += 1 ))
> done

echo $count
1959
```

sure will work for 900 files

`for` loop with globbing can be used to process each file in a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="*txt"

for file in $filename
do
#Do something
done
```

Bash performs filename expansion on expressions that globbing recognizes.

Comment: @maihabunash only limited by the number of files in the directory